# Android - placing booth fixed size and dynamic size view in row

Tags: android

I have a dynamic size RelativeLayout containing TextView with a arbitrary text. Also i have fixed size TextView with timestamp. I want to place both RelativeLayout and TextView with timestamp in one line, side by side.

Like this:

[image: What I want to get]

What I'm really getting:

[image: What I'm really getting]

As you can see, layout with text just occupies the entire width.

XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/news_list_element"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:paddingRight="8dip"
                android:paddingLeft="17dip"
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                android:paddingBottom="4dip">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/news_list_text"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:padding="3dip"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView android:id="@+id/messages_dialog_timestamp_in"
          android:background="#000000"
          android:text="12:05"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_list_element"
          android:paddingBottom="9dip"
          android:paddingLeft="0dip"
          android:textColor="#8f9eac"
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/news_list_text" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
    /> 
    <TextView android:id="@+id/messages_dialog_timestamp_in" 
        android:background="#000000" 
        android:text="12:05" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="9dip" 
        android:paddingLeft="0dip" 
        android:textColor="#8f9eac" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
    />
```

The `android:layout_gravity="left"` will make the message TextView start from the left edge of the parent.

The `android:layout_gravity="right"` will put the timestamp Textview on the right edge of the parent.

The `android:layout_width="0dp"` combined with the `android:layout_weight="1"` in the message TextView will cause it to expand to fill all remaining space **after** all other widgets are in place and have their required space set aside (so it won't push the timestamp off the screen).

This layout will be a little different from what you show as even with short messages the Textview area will expand to fill the available space and make the timestamps all appear in a vertical line on the right edge (which would look neater IMO).